# Splitting emoji, safely

Tags: javascript, emoji

I'm attempting to split a string into single words/chars, but I'm having trouble when it comes to emoji.

First of all, I can't simply split the string using an empty character because emojis are generally have length >= 2.

```
"".split("")
["�", "�"]
```

I found an [emoji regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) that mostly works, but now I am seeing some strange flesh-colored blocks. I even see them show up on twitter in some cases.

[image]

Here's a pen that illustrates the problem with the fleshy blocks
http://codepen.io/positlabs/pen/QyEOEG?editors=011

[image]

UPDATE -----------

Trying out spliddit, and I'm still seeing the issue with the skin tone characters. Is there some way to glue them back together?

http://codepen.io/positlabs/pen/rxLqwL?editors=001

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript's strings are UTF-16, so your emoji is internally represented as two code units:

```
> "\ud83d\ude0e" === ""
true
```

The `String.prototype.split` function doesn't really care about [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) in UTF-16, so it naively reverses the individual code units and breaks your emoji, because JavaScript doesn't provide any way to deal with individual characters in strings.

There's no easy way to deal with it. You need a library like [spliddit](https://github.com/essdot/spliddit) to handle the individual code units properly.

<sup>I'm not 100% familiar with the terminology, so please edit my answer as needed.</sup>

Comment: Ok, spliddit is nice, but it still fails to re-combine the skin tone characters. I've made a new pen, and will update my question.

Comment: @positlabs: I don't have time to check it out now, but I'm pretty sure it's codepen acting up. Try deleting all but the flag and the arms and try deleting one of them: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrOoW?editors=001

Comment: @positlabs: Actually, it's just Chrome. My above example works with both Safari and Firefox. Probably a bug. I'll see if there's some workaround.

Comment: Aha, you're right! It's totally Chrome's fault. I suppose I will just delete those characters, for now.

Comment: `★★★★★☆☆☆☆☆`.length
// 10

``.length
// 20

Answer (score 3):

spliddit can't currently correctly split for example this Hindi text into its 5 characters: "अनुच्छेद"

You need the grapheme-splitter library:
https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter
It is a full implementation of the UAX-29 Unicode standard and will split even the most exotic letters, emoji being just one of many use cases

Comment: Seconding `grapheme-splitter`, which helped me solve a similar problem with complex emoji... even keeping an emoji grapheme as complex as `‍♀️` ("Woman Rowing Boat: Medium Skin Tone")  together, without splitting out the skin tone or gender marker.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example showing to use the Grapheme Splitter library mentioned in [Orlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42845649/11950764):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/grapheme-splitter@1.0.4/index.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
  console.log(splitter.splitGraphemes("️‍")); // ['', '', '️‍']
  
  // Compare above output to:
  console.log([..."️‍"]);                 // ['', '', '', '', '️', '‍', '']
  console.log("️‍".split());              // ['\uD83C', '\uDF37', '\uD83D', '\uDC68', '\uD83C', '\uDFFF', '\uD83C', '\uDFF3', '️', '‍', '\uD83C', '\uDF08']
  console.log("️‍".match(/\p{Emoji}/gu)); // ['', '', '', '', '']
</script>
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/zinegateyi/edit?html,output

This library works great for my purposes.

<sup>(Note: I unfortunately couldn't edit this into Orlin's answer due to suggested edit queue being full.)</sup>